# how to display multiple line string values into single line in crystal report

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, crystal-reports-2008

i am currently working in  windows application and crystal report.
In crystal report i want o display multiple line string value in to single line can anyone tell me how to do?

Example:

in database a column contains following value.

"674,AKR appartment,

Chennai-600001"

while i am trying to display the column value in single line in crystal reports

only "674,AKR apparment, " is displayed can anyone tell me how to show the strings in single line.

my output want to display like this " 674,AKR apparment, Chennai-600001 ".

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to replace the NewLine characters to "nothing". You can do this by either changing the select statement, adding some business logic in C# or by using a formula in CR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have connect your report with the crystal report.
2. In crystal report there is option of [Formula Field](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-formula-field.htm). Create the formula field and Add your database field according to your requirement. you can perform your business logic in formula field too. So according your logic you can perform your task

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  The previous answer is good especially if you have conditions to your display.  Another way is use a TEXTBOX then drag and drop the columns in it.